# Hide toolbar in WPF FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, controls

Trying to present a long text in a WPF form and reallly like the possibilities exposed by FlowDocument. My problem is that it automatically shows a toolbar. Anyone knows how to remove it or suggest some other control to display complicated flowing text on a page

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Would the [FlowDocumentScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.aspx) suffice?

You can host your *FlowDocument* in this control and it will be displayed as in the image below.

[image]

Comment: In the words of Mike Myers and Dana Carver, Excellent

Comment: Use the `ScrollViewer` attached properties E.G. `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`.